# TypeError in jQuery. Undefined value although it is defined/existent

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some strange porblem with jQuery. From a web socket I get the following JSON string:

```
{
  "time" : 1373772581860,
  "entries" : {
    "OK" : 2,
    "FASTER" : 1,
    "SLOWER" : 2
  },
  "entriesSize" : 3,
  "setEntries" : true,
  "setTime" : true
}
```

After receiving it I would like to retrieve the values of entries so that I know how many votes OK has, how many FASTER and how many SLOWER. If I try this by saying `msg.data.entries.FASTER` jQuery fails with `TypeError: msg.data.entries is undefined`. Why is that. I tried it in JS Fiddle and it just worked fine. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TsRgt/). Does anybody know why jQuery is acting that strange and different in different environments? Thanks.

Comment: Post your code here, please. Your fiddle doesn't match the code you refer to in your question.

Comment: There is not much more to see but here it is:

     `ws.onmessage = function(msg) {
            
     console.log('Message: ' + msg.data); // works and shows json posted above
     console.log(msg.data.entries.FASTER); // fails

     }`

Comment: You're sure it's parsed, what does `typeof msg.data` return ?

Comment: oh. it says string. thanks for that hint. how exactly would I parse it to json in jquery?

Comment: `var json = $.parseJSON(data.msg);`

Comment: that solved it :) Thanks. Will check type next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parse returned json string to object.

```
var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(msg);
```

Then access required data from decoded object.

e.g. `var time = jsonObject.time;`

Comment: Thats correct as also discussed in the comments of my question. Thanks.